# Comparing Arrays in Java for a Game

Tags: java, arrays

I wondering if someone could help me, I have a game where the computer generates a random 4 digit code, each digit ranging from   0-5. Then the user guesses this code and the computer returns an array that i print out to a string. The array should contain a 6 for every number in the guess that is the correct number in the correct place, a 7 for each number in the guess that is a correct number but wrong spot for it, and finally a 5 for any completely incorrect numbers.

Example,, if the code is:  0143
and the user's guess is:   0451
the array should be:       6775

This is because the 0 is completely correct, the 1 and 4 are in the code, but were guessed in the wrong spot, and the 5 is completely incorrect. Also each digit is in a separate part of the arrays.

This is what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    if (combo[i] == guess[i]) { 
        Pegs[peg] = 6; 
        peg++; 
    } 
} 

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) { 
        if (guess[i] == combo[x] && guess[i] != combo[i]) { 
            Pegs[peg] = 7; 
            peg++; 
        } 
    } 
} 

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    if (Pegs[i] == 0) { 
        Pegs[i] = 5; 
    } 
}
```

The array guess stores the users guess, the array combo is the correct code, Pegs[] is where the compared array is stored, and the int peg just says where to store the value in the array. The problem with this is it doesn't always return the array correctly to what it to do.

Comment: "the array should be: 6775". It's 6757 right?

Comment: Try to make a SCCEE and show us some outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the other methods, you will get into troubles if you have a scenario where

```
int[] combot = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 3};
int[] guess  = new int[] {0, 4, 5, 1};
```

as you'll get an incorrect `[6, 7, 7, 5]` instead of the correct `[6, 7, 5, 5]` because you'll count your last guess `1` in double.

By using <del>two flags array, one for the exact matches and one for the misplaced guess</del> a single flag array, you can achieve much better and accurate results :

** **Edited** ** I reverted it back because I have found that for `combo = [0, 1, 1, 3]` and `guess = [3, 0, 1, 5]`, it was giving an incorrect response.

```
public int[] computeGuess(int[] combo, int[] guess) {
    int[] result = new int[4];

    Arrays.fill(result, 5);  // incorrect values for all!

    boolean[] exactMatches = new boolean[4];  // all initially set to false
    boolean[] misplaced    = new boolean[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (combo[i] == guess[i]) {
            exactMatches[i] = true;
            misplaced[i] = false;  // make sure we don't use this as misplaced
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (i != j && combo[i] == guess[j] && !exactMatches[j] && !misplaced[j]) {
                    misplaced[j] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (boolean b : exactMatches) {
        if (b) {
            result[i++] = 6;
        }
    }
    for (boolean b : misplaced) {
        if (b) {
            result[i++] = 7;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: for this combination you get wrong results: `combo: [0,1,1,3]` and `guess = [1, 1, 5, 1]`

Comment: You need two loops to make exact matches preferred! You probably only need a single boolean array too, I mean, the result already stores why the combo position has been choosen.

Comment: @agim, `combo = [0,1,1,3]` and `guess = [1,1,5,1]` produces the correct result `[6,7,5,5]` as the second `1` is correct and the first `1` (in guess) refers to the third one in `combo`. All other digits are wrong (as `combo` does not have three `1`'s, and does not contain a `5`).

Comment: @owlstead, true. Nice catch about the single boolean array. But I think it finds the correct result as it is.

Comment: If the description is correct (compare the example) the result should be `5,7,6,5`. Sorry, I meant `5,6,7,5`

Comment: @agim, Have you ever played [Mastermind](http://www.web-games-online.com/mastermind/)? The result does not show "where" the correct pegs are, it just shows "if" you have any.

Comment: @YanickRochon I've played it, but that was not part of the question

Comment: @owlstead, the question is *clearly* about the game Mastermind. It wasn't explicitly stated in the question, but it's nonetheless true :)

Comment: @YanickRochon nope never played. If the order of result doesn't matter, than your solution might work. My __updated__ solution finds an ordered result.

Comment: @YanickRochon btw if the order doesn't matter, then I always would sort both arrays - it makes the whole thing much easier to solve and understand :-)

Answer (score 2):

To compare the array you need only the first loop and the inner loop should be executed only if the numbers at the same position are not equal:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Pegs[i]=5;
    if(combo[i] == guess[i]) {
        Pegs[i] = 6;
        guess[i]= -1;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if(combo[i] == guess[j]) {
            Pegs[i]=7;
            guess[j]= -1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: And to assign `5` only if nothing else matches makes the program unnecessarily complicated

Comment: you still have a `peg` left :)

Comment: You mean `Pegs[i]=7;`? I think `i` is OK. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't picking up on the else loop, so i'm never getting the 7 added even though I should.

Comment: I tried with your test data and it gives as expected `[6, 7, 7, 5]`

Comment: Ok, 1 more slight problem, Say you have the combo [1023] and the guess [1412], it shouldn't count the second 1 as Correct and out of position because the other 1 is correct, and there is not a second 1.

Comment: what would be the expected result in this case? The program above would return 6575. Is it what you expect?

Comment: I think you need to match in two loops again.

Comment: I could simply "consume" the numbers in guess - it means when matching, I assing to -1 and that's it..